# Safari13 webdriverio click issue

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

After updating safari 12 to safari 13, am facing click issues in webdriverio.
Below is the error.

> element not interactable: unknown error

I tried adding custom method using browser.addCommand in before hooks wdio.conf.js but webdriver throws error -

> jsClick is not a function

Below is the custom method added to before hooks. I have added few custom methods on browser scope earlier which works fine. I want 'click' functionality to work on all elements/selectors. I don't want to pass selectors as argument/paramater to new click function. I want webdriverio to work same way like $(selector).click().

```
browser.addCommand(
      'jsClick',
      function() {
        const selector = this.selector
        browser.execute(function(selector) {
          document.querySelector(selector).click()
        }, selector)
      },
      true
    )
```

Any comments/suggestions will be helpful. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with Safari 13 webdriver. Some state it's working with the Safari Technology Preview version: https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/4565#issuecomment-560542745

But I can't confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that works for click issue with Safari13. Adding this wdio.conf works for me -

```
browser.addCommand(
      "jsClick",
      function(childNode) {
        const selector = this.selector;
        browser.execute(
          function(selector, childNode) {
            var targetNode = "";
            if (childNode) {
              targetNode = document.querySelectorAll(selector)[childNode];
            } else {
              targetNode = document.querySelector(selector);
            }
            //--- Simulate all possible natural mouse-click sequence.
            simulateEvent(targetNode, "mouseover");
            simulateEvent(targetNode, "mousedown");
            simulateEvent(targetNode, "mouseup");
            simulateEvent(targetNode, "click");

            function simulateEvent(node, eventType) {
              var clickEvent = new MouseEvent(eventType, {
                bubbles: true,
                cancelable: true
              });
              node.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
            }
          },
          selector,
          childNode
        );
      },
      true
    );
```